# LG P880 - No keyboard after factory reset

Tags: adb, factory-reset, keyboard, usb-debugging, lg-optimus-4x

yesterday I tried to reset my rooted phone (LG Optimus 4X HD) because I thought it would run faster after a factory reset.

Unfortunately I didn't remember that I uninstalled the stock keyboard and now, there is no keyboard installed on the device.
This makes it impossible to get past the setup wizard.

I tried sideloading a keyboard apk via adb but it failed (error message: verifying package ... installation aborted). I also failed to connect the device to the PC suite (I presume this is the case because USB debugging is turned off).

Is there anything else I could try?

Thank you in advance

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје No I can't. I have to create a google account or setup my existing account. Both are not possible without a keyboard.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје I am not able to skip the setup ... Theres no 'skip' button. Do you own the exact same phone?

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје I've done it  Turned off wifi and cellular data during the setup wizard and then it was possible to proceed without a google account. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје You can do that if you want to ;)

Comment: Ok, I cleared comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this: 
Simply skip setup wizard (turn off cellular data to be able to do this), then when get to launcher turn on bluetooth and transfer keyboard .apk file and install it (check unknown sources to do this). Than go to play store and login to google account. To prevent this from happening again use titanium backup and convert keyboard to be system app.